# Incorrect width with Intrinsically sized UICollectionView in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, flowlayout

I am working on a user interface with a complex combination.  I have a `UITableView` at the outermost level.  I have a custom cell inside of it which contains a `UICollectionView`.  Each cell in the collection view contains a label with varying amounts of text.  The cells size dynamically, as should the collection and the row in the table to accommodate various selections.

[image: Visual of description]

The problem I am encountering is that the collection is only showing four cells, when there should be six.  I put some println statements in my subclass of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and can see within `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect` that it gets called several times -- at first the width of the collection has not been autosized so the `collectionViewContentSize` thinks it is wider, explaining why the collection view only expands to show two lines.  However, by the last time `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect` is called, the width is right and there should be more rows, but the sizing of the collection view already seems to be set by this point.

Here you can see what the wider view shows:
[image: Landscape View]

Does anyone have any idea how I could either force auto layout to allocate vertical space for the collection AFTER the width is set for the collection OR set the width of the collection EARLIER?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Two follow up questions... 1) Is `isScrollEnabled` set to `false` for your collection view instance, and 2) is the collection view free to expand it's height (e.g. no constant height constraint, or pinned top and bottom anchors?)

Comment: please add your current code snippets to better investigate your code

Comment: How are you setting the height of your table view cell that holds the collection view?

Comment: @MatthewS isScrollEnabled is set to false, and it actually does expand depending on the number of items in the collection -- but the height is being calculated based on a CollectionView width of 512, rather than the significantly smaller size Autolayout gives it on an iPhone -- it just seems that by the time the correct width is applied, the collectionViewContentSize that is being used has already been returned.

Comment: @muescha, I will try to get some appropriate snippets but there are a lot of moving parts -- probably why this does not work.